# Select a number of objects from a group with identical objects

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling with this combinatorics problem:

> A box contain $50$ white balls, $30$ red balls, $10$ black and $10$ green balls. We take $20$ balls from the box without replacement. What's the possibility of at most $2$ among $20$ balls being black?

This is how I approached the problem.

In total we have $\dbinom{100}{20}$ ways to select $20$ from $100$ balls. This is our denominator. We have $\dbinom{90}{20}$ ways to select $20$ balls, in which no black ball is contained. $\dbinom{91}{20}\dbinom{10}{1}$ ways to select $20$ balls, in which one black ball is contained. $\dbinom{92}{20}\dbinom{10}{2}$ ways to select $20$ balls, in which $2$ black balls are contained.

The possiblity of at most $2$ balls being black is therefore:
$$\frac{\dbinom{90}{20} + \dbinom{91}{20}\dbinom{10}{1} + \dbinom{92}{20}\dbinom{10}{2}}{\dbinom{100}{20}}$$

I don't really think this is correct but I also don't know how else I can solve this problem. I'd be grateful for any feedback (This is my first post so I'm sorry in advance for any formatting error.)

Comment: Use dollar signs for LaTex: `${n \choose k}$` gives ${n \choose k}$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll read more on hypergeometric probabilities.

Comment: @Henry so I just watched a video on hypergeometric probablities, shouldn't the answer be ${90 \choose 20} + {90 \choose 19}{10 \choose1} + {90 \choose 18}{10 \choose 2}\over {100 \choose 20}$ instead?

Comment: The answer you included in your comment is correct.

Comment: @FoxT. Indeed you are correct in you comment rather than your question